# A bunch of questions

Tags: wireless, drivers

I've been using Ubuntu on and off (mostly off) since 11.10.

I'm probably not going to switch my main desktop to Ubuntu anytime soon, but I would like to use it on my netbook.

So here's the thing(s), it probably will work great except for some parts of which I'm not so sure about.

I'm aiming to use Ubuntu 14.10, the thing is my netbook is pretty weak, so I installed a Broadcom Crystal HD -70015(i think)- to make it play HD videos, and in windows after messing around with it for a while, it works great, I can watch 720/1080p video fluently which used to be impossible before.
Also since I replaced the wifi card with the crystal hd, I bought a usb wireless adapter ([http://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-150Mbps-Raspberry-Supports/dp/B003MTTJOY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1416004534&sr=8-1&keywords=edimax+wifi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY))

Long story short is the Crystal HD card still supported in 14.10?
What are the exact steps that I  have to take in order to get it working? (fresh install)
Is my wireless adapter (linked above) supported?

Thanks,
Raif.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the Broadcom Crystal HD is supported by the upstream Linux kernel, but Broadcom does [provide drivers for Linux](http://www.broadcom.com/support/crystal_hd/). I don't know if they work with the latest kernels though, as the site says *>= 2.6.11*, but the kernel in 14.10 is version 3.16.

The USB WiFi adapter you link to claims Linux support, but I do not know if drivers are included in the upstream kernel. It may come with drivers you will need to install or compile. If you already have one, check any CD that came with the adapter for drivers. Edimax also has a [driver download](http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pl1_idSelect=support.php%3Fpl1_id%3D28%26mwsp%3D1&pl1_id=28&pd_id=347&button=Go) available. Looking at the Edimax driver, it appears to be a Realtek RTL8188C/8192C chip, so may be supported by upstream kernel.

The best way to check, is to simply create a bootable USB installer disk, boot the live Ubuntu system, and see if your devices are recognized and work appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, but I already found the linux driver when I was looking fo the driver on windows. I did have the same concerns about wither it would work on newer kernals or not. Also I'm not really linux savvy, so I was wondering how to install such drivers. One more thing, I can't seem to make a bootable 14.10 usb, I tried unetbootin and universal usb installer, it seems like a common issue.